# libGLU.so.1 error loading shared library

Tags: installation

I am trying to install blender 2.79 on ubuntu 17.10.
Downloaded  blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 from

https://www.blender.org/download/

ran the command: `sudo tar xvjf blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2`

changed directories to the blender executable and ran the command:
 `./blender`

Got this error:

`./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If I run `/sbin/ldconfig -p`
I get the line:
`libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1`

So I'm guessing I need to link to it somehow?
I tried
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib`
which didn't work, and maybe I've made things worse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed I need libGLU.so.1 not libGL.so.1. So I'm missing a library I need to install?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Running the libglu1 installation addressed this. I'm running Blender 2.79 on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1
```

Answer (score 1):

used lubuntu's synaptic package manager to install libglu1-mesa and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Install glu

```
Sudo pacman -Sy glu
```